# Generate a sequence of numbers from human-readable input

Tags: bash, unix

In bash, I have a program that lists several choices of files to download, then prompts the user to select some. I'd like the user to be able to type in something like `1-6,8,11-12` to download files 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 11, and 12. How can I generate a sequence of numbers (to put into a `for` loop) from this type of human-readable input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo 1-6,8,11-12 | tr -cd "0-9,\n-" | tr "," "\n" | while IFS=- read A B; do eval echo {$A..${B:-$A}}; done | tr "\n" " "
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 11 12
```

Comment: Mine outputs {1..6} {8..8} {11..12}. Bash version 4.3.25(2)-release (on FreeBSD)

Comment: Very neat solution! Pity it doesn't work for @Suchipi - perhaps brace expansion is not on by default in FreeBSD, and `set -B` is needed.

Comment: @Suchipi: I have tested it with bash 4.3.11(1)-release (Ubuntu 14.04). Try `eval` with quotation marks: `echo 1-6,8,11-12 | tr -cd "0-9,\n-" | tr "," "\n" | while IFS=- read A B; do eval "echo {$A..${B:-$A}}"; done | tr "\n" " "`

Comment: I tried putting `echo {1..10}` in my script and it turns into `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` fine, so it must be something with `eval`. `eval` is a builtin, right? If not, it might be using the wrong `eval`?

Edit: We commented on top of each other. Adding quotes doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Suchipi: eval is a bash builtin.

Comment: Nevermind- I'm just stupid and forgot what my default shell was. Works great!